# ¿Existe un tiempo de espera entre ediciones sugeridas por diferentes usuarios?

Tags: discusión, ediciones-sugeridas, colas-de-revisión, revisiones

Actualmente, me encuentro en el sitio con varias preguntas en las que, por ejemplo, el código está pegado sin usar la herramienta *Ejemplo de Código* (de usuarios nuevos en su mayoría).

Cuando intento editar estas preguntas, y existe otra edición pendiente por revisión, el sitio me avisa (antes de dejarme modificar cualquier cosa) que ya hay otra edición en cola. Todo bien hasta ahí.

Pero veo que esto no sucede (o a lo mejor estoy mal) en la Revisión de las Primeras Publicaciones. Cuando termino de editar una de estas preguntas y presiono el botón "Terminé" (valga la redundancia) pueden suceder dos cosas, me pasan muy a menudo:

- La edición no se envía porque otro usuario ya sugirió su edición y está en cola.
- La edición se envía pero luego me aparece como rechazada con el mensaje: *"Esta edición entró en conflicto con una edición posterior."*

En ambos escenarios me parece un poco molesto, porque en ocasiones te tomas tu tiempo para "arreglar" una pregunta, desenredas un código complejo y tratas de hacerlo amigable a la vista y que se pueda interpretar con facilidad, todo esto para que al final suceda uno de los dos eventos mencionados con anterioridad.

¿Esto sucede solo en las colas de revisión? ¿Porqué en esta instancia no hay un aviso que se muestre antes de?

Solo como ejemplo del segundo caso:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/142840

PD: No termino de entender cómo el usuario @Comunidad rechaza las ediciones, es automático? https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/135558

Comment: El usuario @Comunidad no es un usuario normal, simplemente indica que tu edición se rechazó por otro usuario con permisos de edición que lanzó una edicion propia antes que la tuya, o por el OP. En el ejemplo que pones, si te fijas, el OP pulsó en Rechazar y Editar. Al no tener el op permisos para rechazar una edición, es el usuario comunidad el que asume ese rechazo. Es un poco complicado de explicar

Comment: En cuanto a que es un poco molesto editar un post y que alguien se te adelante, echando por tierra tu trabajo...es verdad, sucede y ahora mismo no hay nada que hacer. Yo normalmente copio el texto de mi edición, y si la que se me ha adelantado no es buena, vuelvo a editarla y pego lo que estaba haciendo :)

Comment: ¿Se puede enviar una petición o solicitud para que esto no suceda? Lo siento pero no conozco a fondo como proceder en estos casos.

Comment: Aunque puedes publicar la sugerencia aqui en es.meta (como has hecho), la realidad es que es difícil que la sugerencia llegue a los que realmente tienen poder de decisión (y de programación). Esto ha cambiado algo desde la llegada de [Nicolas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), pero donde se podría solicitar con mas posibilidades es en [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). De todas maneras, creo recordar que cosas similares se han solicitado en el pasado sin respuesta o con respuesta negativa. Estoy buscando algun enlace para ponerte.

Comment: [Aqui](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309441/simultaneous-editing-exact-same-timestamp-no-warning-when-overwriting-other) tienes una sugerencia muy similar a la tuya por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, por a revisar esa discusión

Comment: Realmente es molesto que pierdas toda una edición, no es muy buena UX. Como consuelo, decir que cuando tengas el [privilegio de editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) podrás ver si hay ediciones pendientes y aprobarlas o mejorarlas. Así creo que en ese punto ya no tendrás este problema. Mientras tanto, se me ocurre que cuando vayas a enviar algo, antes guardes el código de lo que propones por si se pierde. Así más tarde podrás sugerirlo de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia @fedorqui, lo tendré en cuenta